# Using Delimiters angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have text area box in that i will type emails with comma separated then ng List directive split those emails into array now i want to add  new line separation also for example when i type emails separated with comma or new line then those emails need to store in arrays.

My code here

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" ng-model="names" ng-list></textarea>
```

[see this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/0QPtHd2Qui6ztnltTSOD?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see demo here

http://plnkr.co/edit/ot3fkEPBBeK7OoeH6LBZ?p=preview

add ng-change to your textbox

```
 <textarea rows="4" cols="50" ng-model="names" placeholder="Enter your emails" ng-change="split(names)"></textarea>
```

and in your controller add that

```
   ....
        $scope.namesList = [];       
        $scope.split = function() {
         var names = $scope.names.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,",").split(',')
         $scope.namesList = names

        }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do a replace then split something like:

```
var names = $scope.names.replace('\n', ',').split(',')
```